# How to ensure non-null duplicate values are not inserted in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have a history database in `SQL Server 2005` that is used to archive data from live database. I need to add a column in history database named RowID INT. This column cannot be made as identity since it need to store values from live database.

Note: In the live database the RowID is identity column. This column was added by me in live database also recently.

I need to make sure that in history database, the non-null values inserted into this column is unique. I understand that in SQL Server, we cannot make a nullable column as unique.

So, in SQL Server 2005, what is the most efficient way to make sure that insertion of `non-null duplicate values` into RowID columns throws an error?

Comment: you said RowID in Live is Identity.  How did you get duplicates inserted there?

Comment: @techspider In Live database, it never become duplicate. But in history database there can be multiple attempts be made to archive. If the RowID is already present it should fail in history database.

Comment: How do archive? is it script or tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is time to upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server. Microsoft is discontinuing support in April (2016) (see [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-2005/)).

Starting in SQL Server 2008, you can trivially do what you want with a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_history_rowid on history(rowid) where col is not null;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) for RowId